# Set zPanel to exchange email remotely

Tags: php, wordpress, email, centos, zpanel

I am using zPanel (not cPanel) to host a WordPress website and the contact form is not working. The form worked fine when the site was hosted on a cPanel VPS. I do not get any errors and the message should be going through just fine, but it is not.

I think that zPanel is trying to exchange the emails locally. Is there some way that I can force it to exchange emails externally?

What I am looking for is the zPanel equivalent of cPanel's "Remote Mail Exchanger".

I need to configure the server to not accept mail locally and send mail to the lowest MX record.

Again, this is a zPanel issue not a cPanel issue.